# omni-completetion for the instance of Request Class, how to choose next Request?

Tags: php, vim

I ran `ctags --recursive` at the root folder of my project where my zend framework library files were located.

i know that i can navigate to the source of a tag using `:ta`, and if the tag has more than one source, i can get a list of the sources and navigate using (for `Request` tag) `:ts Request` and then choose the source i want, like:

[image: VIM output for ts Requesr]

but when i am in insert mode and wanna use omni completion i will get

[image: omni-completion result based on tags]

this is the functions of `composer.phar` Request Class (1st result of ts). how can i make omni-completion understand that i want another `Request` class functions, completed?

Comment: You can't. Just like with `:tag`, there's no way for Vim to know that you want the `Request()` from `Request.php` and not the one from `composer.phar`. Especially if both files are included.

Comment: I guess `ctags` are `grep` based look up. You need more intelligent IDE/plugin which is context sensitive.

Comment: @SparKot: Do you know any intelligent plugin? i am not insisting on using the omni-completion vim provides.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "intelligent" PHP completion plugin. There's a fork of the default one that fixes a few limitations in the original but it doesn't go much further. If you want real code-aware completion, get yourself an IDE. Well, you could try eclim, too.